# Download pretrained ImageNet model of ResNet, VGG, etc. (.PB file)

Tags: python, tensorflow, pre-trained-model

I have downloaded a pre-trained model on ImageNet of Inception v3 from http://download.tensorflow.org/models/image/imagenet/inception-2015-12-05.tgz (found this link while following one of the tutorials on codelabs).

This zip file contains .pb file that I can directly import as GraphDef in TensorFlow.

I would like to know if there are similar .pb files for other architectures as well, such as ResNet, VGG16, MobileNet, etc. If yes, could you provide the link of those?

Thanks in advance.

Kind Regards,

Ajay

Comment: There is a deleted response referencing https://modelzoo.co/,  which seems like a valid resource as well.  Is there a reason to avoid modelzoo? I'm not sure why the response was down voted, leading to the author deleting it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can find many pretrained models here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim#pre-trained-models

And the corresponding codes are here: 
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim/nets

Answer (score 3):

Here are addition sources to download pretrained models:

- TensorFlow Hub: https://tfhub.dev/
- ModelZoo: https://modelzoo.co/

Though slightly different, Keras provides an interface to access pretrained models:

- https://keras.io/api/applications/